# Neoj4 NeoDash Natural Language Query Generation - TypeError: v.setDriver is not a function

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, neodash

In Neo4j's NeoDash, I'm trying to setup natural language querying. Both Neo4j and NeoDash are installed locally on my desktop and I've registered APOC on my database. I enter a test query in English and when I press the Transalate button I get the following error message:

> TypeError: v.setDriver is not a function

How can I manage to find the root cause and resolve it?

[image: NeoDash]

[image: Error message]

**Update:**

I have the desktop version of Neo4j on my PC. The database is retrieved from a dump file downloaded from my company's server and works flawlessly on Neo4j Browser and Neo4j Bloom.
The database has been created using Neo4j 5.16.0 so I installed the same version to load it.

[image: Neo4j Desktop]

[image: Neo4j Browser]

I registered the APOC from the user interface as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: APOC registeration]

Comment: Pls share how you  installed locally on your desktop and I've registered APOC. In this way, we can trace what the potential problem is. Thanks.